# React bootstrap onclick list-group-item highlight the item/ active

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I have 2 panel with list group on each panel. I am using bootstrap.

**Issue:** 
onclick first list-group-item on panel 1 it changing `style = "success"`, but when I click on the second list-group-item on panel 1 style change to "success" but not changing the first list-group-item style to default (`style = ""`).

onclick on list-group-item it should change style or active or change the background color. Highlight the selected item and remove it when click on another item on the respective panel. 
Alternative   `<ListGroupItem href="#" active>`

my code: [Code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-k8yvpw)

Answer (score 4):

On `onSelectDevice` function your setting `card.style = "success";` to  both buttons A and B.

But your not resetting the old style to empty when clicking on B.

either you can do like @Guillermo Quiros solution or you can setState again `this.state.cards` like below :

```
let showPropContainer = this.state.cards.slice() or [...this.state.cards];
let cards = showPropContainer.map((val, index) => {
    val.esn === card.esn ? val.style="success" : val.style=""
    return val;
});
this.setState({ selectedCard: card , cards})
```

Full solution available [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-fxqxqv)

Comment: Thank you but I found **Guillermo Quiros** bit easy. I will go through your code and understand.

Answer (score 1):

I once had the same problem and here is how I solved it

```
      <ListGroupItem
        key={note.id}
        onClick={(id) => handleItemClick(note.id)}
// here on the href attribute I appended an Id just to make it somehow different and it worked for me. 

        href={`#${note.id}`} >

        <h6>{note.title}</h6>
      </ListGroupItem>
```