# Desiggning a nice looking user account dashboard with react-bootstrap

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

So I'm looking for advice. This is my first job, and I'm trying to make a dashboard. Basically, the design idea is to use a react-bootstrap card for a profile picture and some info, another card with basic clickable options, and when a user clicks on an option, another card is rendered to the right of it, containing more specific list items.

I have no clue how to do clickable ListGroup.Item, nor do I know how to make it render/remove additional page components.

Any help would be appreciated!

My main panel is a column of width 4, and I'll be using no more than 3 columns, so 12 more than 12 cells wide.

Comment: Does [React bootstrap onclick list-group-item highlight the item/ active](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52160077/react-bootstrap-onclick-list-group-item-highlight-the-item-active) contain useful information for you?

Comment: No, sadly. I know how to mark them as active, I just want to populate a different column with another list depending on which item I click.